# Binding mysql data into Combobox in javafx

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, combobox

I'm new in javafx I can't come up a solution with this.

I have mysql table `people`.

```
------------------ 
id        |  name  
------------------ 
int,ai,pk | string
------------------
```

I want to populate data into combobox only the list of `name` and then every time i click the combobox, the value should be the `id`. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this demo! where, `id_value` is the related `id` of the `name`.

```
public class PopulateComboBoxDemo extends Application {

    private ComboBox<String> people = new  ComboBox<>();
    private List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
        this.populateData();

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(); 
        root.setCenter(people);     
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        people.setOnAction(e -> {
            int index = people.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            //here is the id_value
            String id_value = ids.get(index);
            System.out.println("The id of " + people.getItems().get(index) + " is : " + id_value);
            //
            //.........
            //
        });     
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }   

    private void populateData() {
        this.people.getItems().clear();
        this.ids.clear();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","user","password");
            String sql = "select name, id from person";
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            int index = 0;
            while(rs.next()) {
                this.people.getItems().add(index, rs.getString("name"));
                this.ids.add(index, String.valueOf(rs.getInt("id")));
                index++;
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PopulateComboBoxDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JPA to manage your relational data then this code should do the job, otherwise you will have to map your table rows to objects first.
Good luck !

```
 List<People> PeopleList = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM People p").getResultList();
    ObservableList<People> peopleData = FXCollections.observableList(PeopleList);
    PeopleList.add(null);

 yourCombo.setCellFactory((comboBox) -> {
        return new ListCell<People>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(People item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText("Select");
                    yourCombo.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                } else {
                    setText(item.getName();
                }
            }
        };
    });


        yourCombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<People>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(People people) {
            if (people == null) {
                return "Select";
            } else {
                return people.getName();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public People fromString(String nameString) {
            return null; // No conversion fromString needed.
        }
    });



    yourCombo.setItems(peopleData);
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. i'll check your code later if i'm going to use JPA cuz currently i'm using my custom code entity for people.. im going to study jpa first.. thank you so much in advance..